# Is $[0,\infty )$ a closed interval or a half-closed interval?

Tags: interval-arithmetic

Is $[0,\infty)$ a closed interval or a half-closed interval?

My confusion is whether infinity is included or not.

Comment: Is $(-\infty,0)$ open? What's the complement of such set?

Comment: @Derek: What metric is use here? In other words, from what mathematical context is your question?

Comment: @Derek A round bracket indicates that it is not included. A square bracket that it is included. So in this case 0 is included, but infinity is not.

Comment: it is a half closed interval

Answer (score 3):

This is a closed set wrt. euclidean metric. Namely, if $x_n\ge 0$ and $x_n\to x$, then $x\ge 0$, which proves the closedness.

Comment: what is x here?

Comment: In another words - I have proved that a limit of any sequence of this set belongs to this set. Then \(x\) is a limit of arbitrarily chosen sequence of this set.

Answer (score 3):

$ \infty $ is not included !

By definition: $[0, \infty)=\{x \in \mathbb R: x \ge 0\}.$

$[0, \infty)$ is closed, as SZW1710 has outlined.

Comment: isn't infinity part of the set, so infinity must be included if the set is closed then infinity closed?

Answer (score 0):

It is closed.

Usually, one defines a [*closed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set) set $B$ as a set whose complement $B^c:=X\setminus B$ is *open*. Regardless, $[0,\infty)$ is closed iff its complement is open. In this case, it may help to write it like this:

$[0,\infty)^c=\{\,x\in\mathbb{R}\,\mid x\geq 0\,\}^c=\{\,x\in\mathbb{R}\,\mid x<0\,\}=(-\infty,0)$

(Since by taking the complement we are negating the statement in the set builder.) This is clearly an open set, so $[0,\infty)$ was closed. The answer given by szw1710 is also good, since if a set contains all its limit points, it is closed.

The confusion is of course rooted in the feeling that we should have $[0,\infty]$ for it to be a closed set, otherwise it seems it would only be half-closed. This is probably what you mean by 'whether infinity is included or not'. Now, $\infty$ is not a real number, so it would not make sense to talk about $[0,\infty]$ unless you were talking about the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). But, even so, as has hopefully been demonstrated, $[0,\infty)$ is closed, and of course so is $[a,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,a]$ for any real number $a$. What we would call *half-closed* (*half-open*) is something like $[3,5)$, whose complement is $(-\infty,3)\cup [5,\infty)$, which is a union of one open and one closed interval. (There are also sets which are both open and closed, such as the whole space $\mathbb{R}$, these are called [*clopen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set).)